# Getting started with AJAX with ASP.NET 3.5, what do I need on the server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have the .net framework 3.5 on my development machine and also am using the AJAX toolkit  in my code.  In order to publish this code to a server for my users, do I need anything on the server in order for my AJAX code to operate correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only the .NET framework 3.5.

If you publish your project, the AJAX Toolkit used will be also copied over. If you only reference the AJAX Toolkit via file, not via project, then be sure you set the dll to "Copy always" in the properties window.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 3.5 needs to be installed on the server.  The Ajax Control Toolkit assembly does not need to be actually loaded on the server, but needs to be at least in the Bin Folder, with references in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you will need to install the .NET Framework on your server. If you are using the AJAX Toolkit you will want to copy over the AjaxControlToolkit.dll to the bin folder of your web application on your server.

Also want to make sure that you set your web application to use .NET Framework 2.0. In IIS you go to the properties of your web site, then the ASP.NET tab and make sure ASP.NET version is set to 2.0.